# Modal popup that interact with user action like Maximize, Minimize, Close, Resize and Draggable on user setting

Tags: javascript

I need modal popup that interact with user action like below snap. But this modal popup should be in pure java script. Strictly prohibited to use JQuery or JQuery plugin.

[image: Sample modal popup]

I look forward to hearing from you.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I share some plugins which are basically created in Jquery and Javascript.

Whatever you are looking for in plain javascript than you can use http://alpha.jspanel.de/media/demos/nojquery/index.php

Another one is in created using Jquery. It is https://lobianijs.com/site/lobipanel#examples

Using of first option, you can go ahead to active user interaction actions in plain javascript.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, first link should be helpful to me for appropriate result in plain javascript.

Comment: First link is dead

Answer (score 0):

1. Design `div` or something to look like window

   - CSS
   - HTML
2. Add some JS listeners to it: `onClick`, `onDrag` and so on

   - JavaScript
3. Use some combinations of `preventDefault` and `return false` for "modality", also use `z-index` to bring "window" to the top

Comment: Please review below link. I am looking for such kind of functionality that link provides but only my limitation is to use pure javascript :)

https://lobianijs.com/site/lobipanel#examples

Comment: I got the point. 
My suggestion to you is first to implement functionality with jQuery or another lib and than try to translate jq-implementation to pure JavaScript.
It would be educational and really not that hard (especially if you don't need all that animation stuff).

Comment: Here is all you basically need to figure out on plain JS:
1. how to control CSS properties of elements;
2. how to add/copy/remove elements on the page;
3. how to do D'n'D and Click listeners;